# Blender export to fbx error ,edit mode -face menu -intersect (boolean) error

Tags: modifiers, export, error, .fbx

My work in object mode , looking everthing fine , the you can see holes is not put on by modifiers booleam , it is put on by a option in edit mode- face menu - intersect(boolean) i dono where it is the issue or what[![picture in edit mode .picture after exporting to .Fbx file and opened in windows 3d viewer, everthing is looking worse , and on every place i used the option mentioned above and the objcet im fbx file is filled or somewhat trying to merge the vertex or anything i dono what is going on , but when i tried exporting to stl it is opening a windows 3d paint software and looking fine everything, but i want to export in fbx with all fine[![object mode image [ as mentioned above the holes are all put by option in edit mode face menu intersect boolean[[image: Image in fbx file opened in windows 3d viewer, looking like everthing is trying to merge or fill . [ while exporting selected the apply modifiers options and path to copy with its icon clicked3rd image showing in edit mode close view ]1]image after exporting to .fbx , [image: image in object mode]Image in edit mode mode looking fine , [image: Object mode image] in object mode , many holes looking their are put on by a option in edit mode face menu intersect boolean.

Comment: Fix formatting please, you have 3 pictures collapsed into one, hard to understand what do you mean

Comment: @Crantisz editted please check now bro , and please gimme a solution iam like trapped after doing this much long work